# Integral $\int \sin({|x|})\,dx$ is this correctly done?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

$$\int \sin({|x|}) \,dx = ?$$

I know that

$$|x| =
  \begin{cases}
                                   x & \text{if $x \geq 0$  } \\
                                   -x & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
  \end{cases}$$

Now the two cases of $\int \sin({|x|})\,dx$

**CASE I**

When $|x|$ is positive ($x \geq 0$) therefore $\int \sin({|x|})\,dx$ is changed to $\int \sin({x})\,dx$ and that is equal to $-\cos({x})+C$.

**CASE II**

When $|x|$ is negative ($x < 0$) therefore $\int \sin({|x|})\,dx$ is changed to $\int \sin({-x})\,dx$ and this will changed to $-\int \sin({x})\,dx = \cos({x})+ C $.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: oops, i re-edit it.

Comment: Yes, $$\int \sin(|x|)\,dx=\begin{cases}-\cos(x)+C_1&x>0\\\\\cos(x)+C_2&,x<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: As written, your solution has a discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Let $C_2=C_1-2$ and all is well at $0$.

Comment: Your comment follows mine directly.  Hence, I thought that you might be referring to it.

Comment: @MarkViola: as you know, your discontinuity can be fixed, but not the OP's.

Comment: no no no, @YvesDaoust is talking about my answer not yours.

Answer (score 2):

So in summary your splitting in cases (a good idea) shows

$$\int \sin(|x|) dx = \begin{cases} -\cos(x) + C_1 & x >0 \\ \cos(x)+C_2 & x < 0\end{cases}$$

where we have a disagreement on $x=0$, but as we want to find a function that is differentiable and has derivative $\sin(|x|)$ on all of $\Bbb R$ we can take $1+C_2 = -1 + C_1$ to at least have a better behaved (i.e. continuous) function. I 'm not sure if that's what you're meant to do here, but look into it. A priori the constants can be chosen independently of each other on the $x<0$ and $x>0$ parts.

Comment: $x = 0$ because it doesn't exist right.

Comment: @EM4 You'd have to show that even taking constants that match up, we will have a non-differentiable function. It looks from the graph that it *is* actually differentiable at $x=0$ with correct constants (with value $0 = \sin|0|)$ of course).

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)=\sin|x|$ is a continuous function for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there is an antiderivative $F(x)$ such that $F'(x)=\sin|x|$ for all $x$.  Here is such a function:

$$F(x)=-\mathop{\rm sgn}(x)(\cos x-1)$$

where $\mathop{\rm sgn}(x)=1$ for $x\gt0$ and $\mathop{\rm sgn}(x)=-1$ for $x\lt0$. (Note, $F(0)=0$ regardless of how one defines $\mathop{\rm sgn}(0)$, but it's fairly standard to define $\mathop{\rm sgn}(0)=0$.) Thus the indefinite integral can be expressed as

$$\int\sin|x|\,dx=-\mathop{\rm sgn}(x)(\cos x-1)+C$$

Comment: Ah, I see Anton Vrdoljak posted much the same answer while I was writing this one.

Comment: so sgn(x) = $\frac {|x|}{x}$  or $\frac {x}{|x|}$ when the function is symmetric function at x = 0 for this problem?

Comment: @EM4, yes -- in fact I considered using $|x|/x$ instead of sgn($x$).

Comment: so this isn't discontinuity at x = 0 due to the graph from Anton.

Comment: The graph to look at in Anton's answer is the red curve. It is precisely the same as my function $F(x)$ and is continuous and differentiable at all points, including $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**GeoGebra approach**:

$$\int \sin \mid x \mid dx = - \frac{\cos (x \operatorname{sgn}(x))}{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}+\operatorname{sgn}(x) + const$$

[image: Geogebra approach]

Comment: what is sgn(x) mesn?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

Comment: $-\frac{\cos(x\operatorname{sgn}(x))}{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}$ should then be "simplified" to $-\operatorname{sgn}(x)\cos(x),$ which works for all $x$ where the original had a hole.

Comment: The cosine is an even function.  The signum function inside its argument is completely superfluous.

Comment: I agree, and here is WolframAlpha approach: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28abs%28x%29%29+dx

Answer (score 1):

We can address the problem by writing a definite integral one bound of which is zero.

- $x\le0\to\displaystyle\int_x^0\sin(-x)\,dx=1-\cos x$,
- $x\ge0\to\displaystyle\int_0^x\sin(x)\,dx=-\cos x+1$.

This can be compacted to

$$\text{sgn}(x)(1-\cos x)$$

to which you can add a constant.

Comment: YES! :) 

but x < 0 and x > 0 are discontinuity at x = 0.

Comment: @EM4: what do you mean ? The antiderivative is perfectly continuous, by construction. If you prefer, I will change to non-strict inequalities.

Comment: you wrote this,"your solution has a discontinuity at =0" and I was wondering because x < 0 and x > 0 give as the answer.

Comment: @EM4: nope, your solution and mine differ. Pay more attention.